# Curse of Parvathi on Astrological predictions

Tags: scripture, astrology, parvati, curse

I heard a story of curse by Parvathi on Astrological predictions. It is said that the astrological predictions cannot be accurate at all times due to that curse of Parvathi.

I did not remember the story in detail. But, I found a story in [Medium](https://medium.com/@vijay_raghunath/astrology-and-parvathi-edf3d1023562).

Which scripture mentions about the curse of Parvathi to Astrology?